# Android webview video mute using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, android, video, webview

I am trying to play a youtube video in webview e.g *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjWf8A0YNSE*. It is playing fine, but requirement is to mute the video playing. I have used below given code for this:

```
 mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false);
    if (!mIsFragmentUiRender) {
      mBinding.networkNotAvailableWebview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      mBinding.htmlTextWebViewId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
      logContentPlayBackModel(null, AppConstants.ContentPlayBackErrorConstant
          .PLAYBACK_STATUS_YES);
      mBinding.htmlTextWebViewId.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
      mBinding.htmlTextWebViewId.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      mBinding.htmlTextWebViewId.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      mBinding.htmlTextWebViewId.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
      mBinding.htmlTextWebViewId.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
          log(LogLevel.DEBUG, "WEBVIEW_CONSOLE_MSG : " + consoleMessage.message());
          return true;
        }
      });
      mBinding.htmlTextWebViewId.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
//          view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
          return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          mIsWebViewLoaded = true;
          view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {"
              + "var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');"
              + "[].forEach.call(videos, function(video) {video.muted = true});"
              + "[].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { console.log('isVideoMuted: ' + " +
              "video.muted);});"
              + "console.log('total video element');"
              + "console.log(videos.length);"
              + "if (videos.length > 0) {"
              + "console.log('Found Video Element..!!');"
              + "console.log(videos[0].nodeName);"
              + "videos[0].click();"
              + "return;"
              + "} else {"
              + "console.log('Not Found Video Element..!!');"
              + "}"
              + "})()");
          if (IS_AUTO_SCROLL_ENABLE && mContentModel != null) {
            initHandlerAndRunnable();
            scheduleAutoScroll();
          }
        }
```

These are the logs printed by javascript console:

```
D/com.panasonic.android_app.fragments.WebViewFragment: [2019-08-01 16:03:31.743] WEBVIEW_CONSOLE_MSG : The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored.
08-01 16:03:29.548 27778-27778/panasonic.digital.signage.piqa1 D/com.panasonic.android_app.fragments.WebViewFragment: [2019-08-01 16:03:34.242] WEBVIEW_CONSOLE_MSG : isVideoMuted: true
08-01 16:03:29.550 27778-27778/panasonic.digital.signage.piqa1 D/com.panasonic.android_app.fragments.WebViewFragment: [2019-08-01 16:03:34.244] WEBVIEW_CONSOLE_MSG : total video element
08-01 16:03:29.552 27778-27778/panasonic.digital.signage.piqa1 D/com.panasonic.android_app.fragments.WebViewFragment: [2019-08-01 16:03:34.246] WEBVIEW_CONSOLE_MSG : 1
08-01 16:03:29.554 27778-27778/panasonic.digital.signage.piqa1 D/com.panasonic.android_app.fragments.WebViewFragment: [2019-08-01 16:03:34.249] WEBVIEW_CONSOLE_MSG : Found Video Element..!!
08-01 16:03:29.556 27778-27778/panasonic.digital.signage.piqa1 D/com.panasonic.android_app.fragments.WebViewFragment: [2019-08-01 16:03:34.251] WEBVIEW_CONSOLE_MSG : VIDEO
```

I have tried same code on google chrome for same video and it is working fine. I don't know why it is not working on my android device.

Comment: Check your logcat for the javascript logs and add that to your post

Comment: are you using iFrame for youtube video?

Comment: No, i am playing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjWf8A0YNSE directly in webview

Comment: @GiddyNaya Javascript logs added to question

Comment: did you find any solution?